# How to Insert Current date into oracle database from a java program?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

I want to insert the current date to my oracle database Bills. I am getting the date from system using

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
```

is that possible to directly insert it into the database without converting to the default format (`dd-month-yyyy`) of DATE data type in  Oracle?

Comment: Why not just use `CURRENT_DATE` as a value literal in your SQL? `insert into foo (some_date_column) values (current_date)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You should probably use `SYSDATE`, not `CURRENT_DATE`. `SYSDATE` is the date on the server while `CURRENT_DATE` is the date on the client. I'd imagine you almost always want to insert the server's date into the database, not anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not give any context on what interface you are using to communicate with the DB. Assuming plain JDBC, let the driver handle the problem, use a statement object and set the parameter(s) properly:

```
Connection connection = ...
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO <TableNameHere> VALUES (?)");
statement.setObject(1, new java.sql.Date());
statement.executeUpdate();
```

(Error handling and fluff ommited) The JDBC driver will deal with the details on how to format the date as the database wants it. Don't even worry about it.

Comment: More than that, Oracle DB DATE datatype doesn't even have a format.. Sending a String will cause the DB to implicitly convert the String according to NLS_DATE_FORMAT which might be different in some environments

Comment: If there is a session timezone set, does it write the date in that timezone or always UTC?

Answer (score 13):

Just in case you need CURRENT date, use:

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (YOUR_DATE_COLUMN, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) 
VALUES (SYSDATE, 1234, 567);
```

Comment: What's the difference between `SYSDATE` and `CURRENT_DATE` as the person who commented on the question suggested? Edit: Found the answer. `SYSDATE` is the date on the server while `CURRENT_DATE` is the date on the client. So `SYSDATE` is probably almost always the desired one, I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not mandatory to use the default dd/MM/yyyy format in while initializing SimpleDateFormatter. You have a list of options which can match to your requirement. [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)